# How to change a value in a two dimensions NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm new to OC.
In Swift, it's really easy to change a value in a two dimensions array.
Just like this `a[0][0] = "1"`

But I'm really confused now about how to do it in OC.
Thank you for any advice.

```
self.infos = 
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11", @"22", @"33", @"44", @"55", @"66", nil], 
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"aa", nil], nil];
```

For example. how to set `aa` to  `bb`?

BTW, is it right way to declare `infos` in `@interface`?

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* infos;`

Comment: `infos[1]` is a `NSArray`, not a `NSMutableArray` Is they are indeed mutable, then you can do `self.infos[1][0] = @"bb"`. It's missing a `*` in `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *infos;` (XCode should throw an error)

Comment: @Larme sorry for too much typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simple

```
   self.infos[1][0] = @"newValue";
```

or Complex

```
  NSArray*fr = [self.infos objectAtIndex:1];

 [fr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"newValue"];
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can actually write this:

```
infos[1][0] = @"bb";
```

Comment: Oh god! It's Great! But why there are so many complicated methods for accessing?(like remove, replace...)

Comment: Glad it helped! The reason might be that Objective C deals with pointers not only objects (unlike swift). If you think this is the right answer please mark it as correct Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But it seems sh_Khan answered 
a little bit earlier. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Like this：

```
    NSMutableArray *infos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11", @"22", @"33", @"44", @"55", @"66", nil],
                         [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"aa", nil],
                         nil];

[infos[0] setObject:@"1" atIndexedSubscript:0];
```

or

```
infos[0][1] = @"2";
```